# Deleting a poll python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm working on a telegram bot using python-telegram-bot library in python
I want my bot to send a quiz to the user Here is the code:

```
 question = dict_api.get_question()
    word = question['word']
    answer = question['answer']
    options = question['options']
    q = f"What is the translation of the word '{word}'"
    context.bot.send_poll(chat_id=person_id, question=q, options=options, type=Poll.QUIZ, correct_option_id=answer)
```

and i have PollHandler to take care of the response, when the user had responded i want the bot to delete the quiz for the user, how can i do that?

i've tried to delete it by

```
context.bot.delete_message(message_id=update.poll.id, chat_id=chat_id)
```

as someone would delete a message, but it didn't work and i assume because polls are treated differently by telegram.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `message_id` parameter of `bot.delete_message` needs the message id, not the poll id. Note that poll updates don't contain a `message_id`, because polls can e.g. be forwarded, so they can have multiple message_ids even in chats where your bot isn't even a member.

However if you only want to delete the original message, you can e.g. store a mapping poll id -> `(chat_id, message_id)` in e.g. `context.bot_data` and then use `chat_id, message_id = context.bot_data[update.poll.id]` to get the stored values back to delete the message. Note that `context.user/chat_data` can't work for this here, because poll updates are not associated with a specific user/chat and hence `context.user/chat_data` will be `None` in `PollHandler` callbacks.

Instead of storing `(chat_id, message_id)`, you could also just store the `Message` object that `bot.send_poll` returns - then you only have to call `context.bot_data[update.poll.id].delete()`.

Referencos:

- [wiki page on storing data](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Storing-bot,-user-and-chat-related-data)
- docs of [`Message.delete`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.delete)

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.